# How to remove white space on the top for ZPL code label?

Tags: api, base64, label, fedex, zpl

I am trying to set FedEx ShipRequest API and using image format as ZPLII.

**But when I request, I receive below.**

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

**and If I decode with base 64, I get below with ZPL language,**

^XA^CF,0,0,0^PR12^MD30^PW800^POI^CI13^LH0,20
^FO12,301^GB753,2,2^FS
^FO12,567^GB777,2,2^FS
^FO464,170^GB2,129,2^FS
^FO478,208^AdN,0,0^FWN^FH^FDCAD: 118790264/WSXI3400^FS
^FO28,909^A0N,24,24^FWN^FH^FDTRK#^FS
^FO28,967^A0N,27,32^FWN^FH^FD^FS
^FO136,879^A0N,27,36^FWN^FH^FD^FS
^FO32,172^AdN,0,0^FWN^FH^FDORIGIN ID:SCKA ^FS
^FO224,172^AdN,0,0^FWN^FH^FD000000000^FS
^FO32,190^AdN,0,0^FWN^FH^FDTESTING. SHIPPING DEPT^FS
^FO32,208^AdN,0,0^FWN^FH^FDAMAZON.COM^FS
^FO32,226^AdN,0,0^FWN^FH^FDTEST PARKWAY^FS
^FO32,244^AdN,0,0^FWN^FH^FD^FS
^FO32,262^AdN,0,0^FWN^FH^FDTRI, CA 95377^FS
^FO32,280^AdN,0,0^FWN^FH^FDUNITED STATES US^FS
^FO15,313^A0N,21,21^FWN^FH^FDTO^FS
^FO60,311^A0N,38,38^FWN^FH^FDTEST^FS
^FO60,353^A0N,38,38^FWN^FH^FD^FS
^FO60,395^A0N,38,38^FWN^FH^FD9260 MCFADDEN^FS
^FO60,437^A0N,38,38^FWN^FH^FD**TEST LABEL - DO NOT SHIP**^FS
^FO60,479^A0N,43,40^FWN^FH^FDWEST CA 92683^FS
^FO35,521^A0N,21,21^FWN^FH^FD00000000000000^FS
^FO677,673^GB104,10,10^FS
^FO677,683^GB10,112,10^FS
^FO771,683^GB10,112,10^FS
^FO677,795^GB104,10,10^FS
^FO652,611^A0N,43,58^FWN^FH^FDFedEx^FS
^FO708,650^A0N,19,26^FWN^FH^FDExpress^FS
^FO697,691^A0N,128,137^FWN^FH^FDE^FS
^FO21,578^BY2,3^BCN,25,N,N,N^FWN^FD79260 MCFADDEN^FS
^FO21,611^BY2,2^B7N,10,5,14^FH^FWN^FH^FD[)>_1E01_1D0292683_1D840_1D20_1D7946359217400201_1DFDE_1D510087780_1D311_1D_1D1/1_1D22.00LB_1DN_1D9260 MCFADDEN_1DWEST_1DCA_1DTest_1E06_1D10ZED007_1D12Z00000000000000_1D15Z118790264_1D20Z_1C_1D31Z1001921761100009268300794635921740_1D32Z0210_1D34Z01_1D39ZSCKA_1DK112-0625455-1958644_1D_1E09_1DFDX_1Dz_1D8_1D,#_1B_1271_7F@_1E_04^FS
^FO478,262^AdN,0,0^FWN^FH^FDBILL SENDER^FS
^FO12,856^GB777,2,2^FS
^FO494,1052^A0N,43,43^FWN^FH^FD^FS
^FO791,282^AbN,11,7^FWB^FH^FD552J3/C3B2/DCA5^FS
^FO95,913^A0N,53,40^FWN^FH^FD7946 3592 1740^FS
^FO409,862^A0N,51,38^FWN^FH^FB390,,,R,^FD MON - 12 NOV 4:30P^FS
^FO309,914^A0N,51,38^FWN^FH^FB490,,,R,^FD      EXPRESS SAVER^FS
^FO413,966^A0N,40,40^FWN^FH^FB386,,,R,^FD             DSR^FS
^FO495,1008^A0N,44,44^FWN^FH^FB298,,,R,^FD     92683^FS
^FO574,1068^A0N,24,24^FWN^FH^FB120,,,R,^FD CA-US^FS
^FO695,1052^A0N,43,43^FWN^FH^FB100,,,R,^FDSNA^FS
^FO39,1094^A0N,27,32^FWN^FH^FD^FS
^FO75,1155^BY3,2^BCN,200,N,N,N,N^FWN^FD>;1001921761100009268300000000000000^FS
^FO28,1004^A0N,107,96^FWN^FH^FDCZ APVA ^FS
^FO790,685^A0N,13,18^FWB^FH^FDJ182118081501uv^FS
^FO478,172^AdN,0,0^FWN^FH^FDSHIP DATE: 07NOV18^FS
^FO478,190^AdN,0,0^FWN^FH^FDACTWGT: 22.00 LB^FS
^FO478,226^AdN,0,0^FWN^FH^FDDIMS: 10x9x7 IN^FS
^FO328,526^AbN,11,7^FWN^FH^FDREF: OG-ROME-3-BLK^FS
^FO38,540^AbN,11,7^FWN^FH^FDINV: ORD3642065^FS
^FO38,554^AbN,11,7^FWN^FH^FDPO: 112-0625455-1958644^FS
^FO428,554^AbN,11,7^FWN^FH^FDDEPT: ^FS
^FO25,930^GB58,1,1^FS
^FO25,930^GB1,26,1^FS
^FO83,930^GB1,26,1^FS
^FO25,956^GB58,1,1^FS
^FO31,936^AdN,0,0^FWN^FH^FD0201^FS
^PQ1
^XZ

**But if I see this code in ZPL viewer, then it shows as below,**

[Fedex Label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqwTH.png)

It looks like there are some white spaces on the top and cut off the bottom side.

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a normal behavior if you choose to use a thermal label format with document tab, a removable sticky tab with additional shipping information.

Check Fedex Developper Guide document at Thermal Label Element to select the correct label size you want to use.

Comment: Thank you! This helped!